# error when trying to modify project in laravel forge

Tags: git, laravel, github, digital-ocean, laravel-forge

My project is in laravel forge with digitalocean
first I added a collaborator and deleted it and since when I try to modify code  by git push origin master 
I receive this error in the dashboard of laravel forge

```
From github.com:name/project
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
   aad781c..e558842  master     -> origin/master
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    public/css/style.css
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
Updating aad781c..e558842
```

now I receive a new message

```
From github.com:project/name
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
   be3f227..aeddc3a  master     -> origin/master
Auto-merging .idea/workspace.xml
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in .idea/workspace.xml
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

please any help will be appreciated Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the directory where you have your repository on Digitalocean and run

```
git stash
```

when you want to save this modified file for later usage

or

```
git checkout public/css/style.css
```

if you don't need this modified file and you want to get the same file you have in your repo.

Now you can do standard procedure to get modified files from repo (`git pull` or any other way you do it)

Comment: thanks now my problem becomes different see above please in the topic

Comment: It seems you need to manually merge this file, however you should not add to your repository IDE files at all. Try to manually resolve conflict, run `git status` to see any changes made in files, run again `git checkout .idea/workspace.xml` to restore original file, then `git pull` and if you successfully do it, you should update your `.gitignore` file and at there `.idea` directory